# Como puedo hacer 2 condiciones en una misma función

Tags: javascript, html, condiciones

No entiendo como hacer 2 funciones en una misma función, cuando ejecuto la función y por ejemplo pongo un 2011 me sale los 2 mensajes, como hago para finalizar una condición y comenzar otra. También para la otra función como puedo hacer para que me muestre la edad introducida o en el otro caso la edad que fue sumada
Algún consejo porfavor
Este es mi código:

```
    <script language="javascript">
var nombre=""; var apellido=""; var año=0; var edad=0;
function boton1() //Se debe ingresar los datos de la persona y solo debe aceptar el año de nacimiento entre 2000 al 2010, pero si la edad es menor a 15 , generámos un valor aleatorio de la edad y la sumamos a la edad introducida.
{
 nombre = prompt("¿Cuál es su nombre?",""); 
 apellido = prompt("¿Cuál es su apellido?","");
 año = prompt("Ingrese un año entre 2000 y 2010", 0);
 
if((año>=2000) && (año<=2010))
edad=2021-año
else
alert("Los datos son incorrectos, ingrese nuevamente");
 if(edad<15)
azar=Math.floor(Math.random()*edad)
edad2=parseInt(azar)+parseInt(edad)
alert(nombre+" "+apellido+" tiene "+edad+" como la edad fué menor a 15, generámos un valor aleatorio donde obtuvimos al azar el "+azar+", ahora lo sumamos con la edad anterior y así tenga una mayor edad: "+azar+" MAS "+ edad+   "="+edad2);
else
edad=2021-año
}
function boton2()//Debe mostrar los datos introducidos en el boton 1, si es la edad introducida es menor a 15 debe mostrar la edad nueva.
{
if ((edad2>=0) && (edad2<=5))
alert(nombre+" "+apellido+" tiene" +" "+edad2+ " "+"y es un Bebé");
else
if ((edad2>=6) && (edad2<=11))
alert(nombre+" "+apellido+" tiene"+" "+edad2+ " "+"y es un niño");
else
if ((edad2>=12) && (edad2<=16))
alert(nombre+" "+apellido+" tiene"+" "+edad2+ " "+"y es un adolescente");
else
if ((edad2>=17) && (edad2<=21))
alert(nombre+" "+apellido+" tiene"+" "+edad2+ " "+"y es un joven");
else
alert(nombre+" "+apellido+" tiene"+" "+edad2+ " "+"y es muy mayor");
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="button" name="Boton1" value="Ingresar Nombre" onClick="boton1()" />
<input type="button" name="Boton3" value="Mostrar datos de la persona" onClick="boton2()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

una forma de crear mas condiciones es con elseif

```
if ( condición ){
ejecución }

elseif( condicion ){
ejecución }

else { }
```

lo bueno de elseif es que podes agregar tantos como quieras

Comment: Cuando agregues código como respuesta, agregar las comillas ` para encerrar tu codigo puede hacer que se vea mucho mejor

Answer (score 0):

> Revisa tu código en la forma en que utilizas las condiciones en la
> función boton1() tiene errores
>
> Debe tener una logica de este tipo

```
 // var año=2001;
    //var año=2009
var año= 2005
    var edad;
    var edad2;
    if((año>=2000) && (año<=2010))
    edad=2021-año
    if (edad<15){
    azar=Math.floor(Math.random()*edad)
    edad2=parseInt(azar)+parseInt(edad)
    console.log('edad menor a 15  normalizada ', edad2)
    } else{
        edad2=parseInt(edad);
        console.log('edad sin normalizar',edad2)
    }
```